# How can I include jwplayer in my angular app?

Tags: angular, jwplayer

I'm relatively new to jwplayer and I would like to be able to control one video I have in my angular app, I tried adding the script to angular.json but and add the `declare var jwplayer: any;` definition but it doesn't still work when I try a

```
jwplayer(id).on('complete', ()=>{
        console.log("Complete fired - Your content has completed!");
        this.playNextAudio();
```

jwplayer is not defined 
I tried to do

```
window['jwplayer']("myElement").on('complete', ()=>{
        console.log("Complete fired - Your content has completed!");
        this.playNextAudio();
```

but the problem persists. 
Can I get some help please ?

Comment: If it's an external javascript file, you will have to import it in your angular code. This example might help you https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular

Comment: I actually realised after posting this that each video has its own javascript file, so it's like `http://cdn-jwplayer.com/players/MEDIAID-PLAYERID.js`, They expect you to do a `<script src="http://cdn-jwplayer.com/players/MEDIAID-PLAYERID.js"></script>`